# Replacing filenames by ID

Tags: compare

For a website I'm trying to format about 5000 filenames using VBA/Powershell and/or CSV files:

These files currently have filenames like: **blabla_45359_blabla.jpg** and **45359--blabla.jpg** where as 45359 is the ID of the item in our webshop.
I'd like to format these filenames where as only the ID will be the filename... so: **45359.jpg**

I tried making a list within Excel showing all current filenames and tried formatting them by automatically filtering out the ID-part but without any success.

Any tips?

**EDIT: Example**

It really depends on the file name, for example I have a file named: Futterklappe_PrimoLux_60_schwarz_93412_f.jpg
Goal is to automatically rename this file to: 93412.jpg

I have a list of all ID's as well however the files should be renamed to one of these ID's if it matches that certain ID in the file name). There are also some exceptions to the above as some filenames excists of multiple ID's so I would have to make copies of these files and rename them for each ID as well.

Comment: Can we assume that any number in the name is part of the ID you want to keep? Or could you have say `blabla12_999_aah1.jpg` and only want to keep `999`?  If so, can we assume the ID you want to keep is separated by some delimiter, i.e. `-`, `_`, etc?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2339-excel-rename-files-in-a-folder.html

Comment: It really depends on the file name, for example I have a file named: Futterklappe_PrimoLux_60_schwarz_93412_f.jpg
Goal is to automatically rename this file to: 93412.jpg

I have a list of all ID's as well however the files should be renamed to one of these ID's if it matches that certain ID in the file name). There are also some exceptions to the above as some filenames excists of multiple ID's so I would have to make copies of these files and rename them for each ID as well.

Comment: Are these IDs going to at least be 5 digits? Or does the ID always come before the last underscore `_`? We need some kind of constant that can be checked against to make this possible

Comment: Davis, these always 5 digits however the ID is sometimes placed in the middle of the filename.

Comment: So, look for any 5 consecutive numerals. I assume your filenames wil never have 5+ consecutive numbers that are _not_ part of an ID, or are not _entirely_ an ID per se. e.g.: you will never have a filename `blabla_1234567890_test.jpg`, where the ID is only `12345` and you wish to exclude `67890` (or viceversa).

Answer (score 1):

A [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)-based User Defined Function or UDF seems the best worksheet approach.

```
Option Explicit

Function fixFilename(str As String, ndx As Integer) As String
    Dim tmp As String, ext As String
    Static cmat As Object, regex As Object

    If regex Is Nothing Then
        Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With regex
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = False
            .IgnoreCase = True
        End With
    Else
        Set cmat = Nothing
    End If

    With regex
        .Pattern = "\d{5}"
        If regex.Test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            If ndx <= cmat.Count Then _
                tmp = cmat.Item(ndx - 1)
        End If
    End With

    ext = Mid(str, InStrRev(str, Chr(46)))

    If CBool(Len(tmp)) Then _
        fixFilename = tmp & ext

End Function
```

In the following sample image, B5 has been filled right to C5 to collect the second ID.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell, I would just use a regex with a capturing group:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match '(?<ID>\d{5})') {
            $NewName = $Matches.ID + $_.Extension
            $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
        }
    }
```